# how to avoid unnecessary resolved calls

Tags: typescript

Consider **A is a parent** state and B is child state.
how to prevent the resolve **call(A1,A2,A3)** of parent state at the time of child resolved

```
.state(A){

        resolve: {
         A1:{}
         A2:{}
         A3:{}    
                  }
      } .state(A.B){ 
       } }
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: when child is resolved at that time parent is again resolved so there is unnecessary calls for this.so how to prevent parent call again

Comment: I don't even know what you're showing in the code block.  It doesn't even look like legal Javascript and it's completely unclear what it means or what it's doing.  Still don't understand at all what this question means.

Comment: how is this angularjs?

Comment: Please can you create a minimal working example of your issue to help clear up the confusion?

Comment: Please read how to make a [mcve].